# WordPress Homepage Login

Tags: plugins, login

I'm fairly new to WordPress, and I was assigned a project where a WP site would have a homepage for guest users that has a login page. Once they log in, they will be redirected to the main website content which they are unable to see as guests. What they see is just some words like "You need to login before etc..."

The website isn't for the public, but exclusively for a group who has login credentials so they could edit content. Is there any plugin that could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [Force Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/) plugin.

It should allow you to require login for your entire site, but you can filter exceptions for certain pages (like the homepage).

Comment: The plugin works, but first I want to direct them to a static homepage first with all the designs - and once they click login, that'll be the time I direct them to wp-admin page

Comment: In that case, you might want to consider a plugin like [Smart Passworded Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-passworded-pages) which will allow you to protect any child page.